# Python: convert dataframe to html with styling

Tags: python, html, pandas

I would like to transform the dataframes to html tables  and display it as the image below because ultimately I need to be able to paste it on outlook email body.

1. However, I do not know how to include the Table Title 1,2,3,4  as well as the Big Title 1 & 2 like the image below.
2. Also, how can I have the 2 tables displayed side-by-side and a little bit of space in between them as shown image below?
3. How can I get the colour formatting i.e. colour for column header, border colour & alternating row colours like below table?

My four data frames looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Rank': [0,1,2], 
                   'Name': ['AAA','BBB','CCC'],
                   'Value':[1,2,3]})

df.to_html()
```

And I would like to display the following html tables in the outlook email body. How can this be done ?

[image]

Comment: I would start here [pandas Styling](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html), but I'm not sure if the format is maintained when using `.to_html()`.

Comment: Is this styling going to be preserved when I paste the table in outlook email body ? I was told I had to do the formatting in html in order to paste the html table in outlook email body.

Comment: Yes, `df.style` will print to Jupyter notebook a formatted HTML table that you can copy/paste to outlook. Also `df.style.render()` will give you the raw HTML string.

Comment: Can you show me how this can be done with the example above ?